# Move Scale Rotate raster in Qgis

Tags: qgis, raster

I have some archaeological scanned raster that they have a north arrow and a scale bar. There is no grid, no coordinate system.I would like to put those files in a general map. I don't care about the exact position but I would like to keep the scale and the north direction.  So I need some tools like move raster, rotate raster, scale raster
 Are there such tools in QGIS?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are any landmarks on the map? You could georeference it to those objects.

Comment: There is nothing. Some areas are underground now. I need some tools like scale, rotate, move.

Comment: I usually think that in that case it is just easier to use Inkscape. Just put the image in the background. Rotate it and adjust the scale to an even number of pixels. Then just draw the vector layer above the raster file.

Comment: Did you try it out? How did you do? You could answer your own question and earn some points.

Comment: I am still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin [rasmover](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/rasmover/) does the [move part](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lX0HLxdQV8) of what you are looking for.